# How do you get the current failure count for a windows service

Tags: windows-services, reset, counter

I have a service which will fail when certain resources are unavailable. I have configured it to try restarting twice, then send me an SMS on the third attempt. Unfortunately windows only gives you the option to reset the failure count after a certain number of *days*, whereas I really want it to reset on every third failure. The problem is that once the service is running again, *one* more failure will cause it to send another SMS and not even try to restart the service.

So I want to include in my SMS script some code to reset the failure counter. I have found the following registry location:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\

Which contains among other things (binary) settings for failure actions, but no counter as far as I can tell.

The `sc` command lets you query all sorts of stuff, but also doesn't return a failure count.

Ideally I'd like a way to query/reset the failure counter programatically, but a commandline or registry solution would be fine (since I can script them).

Comment: I'm looking into this, I believe you can do it through the WMI /root/cimv2:Win32_Service interface.  I will continue to research and get back to you.

Comment: No ability to do this via the WMI interface.  I'm at a loss as to how to help.  I will continue to do some checking.

Comment: @Wayne: Thanks for looking into it. I'm no win32 api expert so I wouldn't really know where to start. You'd think there'd be a way.

Answer (score 1):

The Win32 API allows you to specify the failure count be reset after X number of seconds, not X number of days.  Look at the dwResetPeriod members of the SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS structure.

A for the failure counter itself, that is maintained privately inside of the SCM, which knows how many times a given service has failed since Windows was booted.  That counter is not accessible for applications to reset manually, or even to query.

Comment: What a shocking inadequacy! It means that behaviour such as "SMS every third failure" isn't possible. Through the API, I could set the reset time so that it coincided with a wait-restart-wait-restart-sms cycle, but A) that assumes predictable failure timing, and B) I don't like configuring a service through the API when the UI can't handle those settings.